# Unable to access batch items in iterator - Torchtext Attribute Error: 'Field' object has no attribute 'vocab'

Tags: python, pytorch, torchtext

I am unable to access batch items from the Iterator object in Torchtext.
Following is the error

> AttributeError: 'Field' object has no attribute 'vocab'

**Code to Recreate Problem**

```
#Access to Drive
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount ('/content/gdrive')
```

```
import numpy as np
import spacy
spacy_en = spacy.load("en")

def tokenize(text):
    return [tok.text for tok in spacy_en.tokenizer(text)]

import torch
from torchtext.legacy.data import Field, LabelField, Iterator

TEXT = Field(sequential=True, use_vocab=True, tokenize=tokenize, lower=True)
LABEL = LabelField(dtype = torch.long, use_vocab=False)  

fields = {"text": ("txt", TEXT), "label": ("lbl", LABEL)}

from torchtext.legacy.data import TabularDataset
train_data, test_data = TabularDataset.splits(path="/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/", 
                                              train="Strong_Train.csv", 
                                              test="Strong_Test.csv", format="csv", fields=fields)


device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

TEXT = Field(sequential=True, use_vocab=True, tokenize=tokenize, lower=True)
LABEL = LabelField(dtype = torch.long, use_vocab=False) 

TEXT.build_vocab(train_data, max_size=10000 )
LABEL.build_vocab(train_data) 

train_iterator = Iterator(train_data, batch_size=1, device=device)
for batch in train_iterator:
    print('hello')
```

**My Analysis of Problem**
As per the error description, 'Field' object is causing the problem; TEXT is the Field object in this code.

`type(TEXT)`

*Output*: torchtext.legacy.data.field.Field

Since the error says,

> Field object has no attribute 'vocab'

accessing 'vocab' should give an error, but it doesn't give an error

`TEXT.vocab`

*Output*: <torchtext.legacy.vocab.Vocab at 0x7fce37b91950>

I am also able to get the length of vocab

`len(TEXT.vocab)`

*Output*: 2

So the question still remains, if there exists 'vocab' attribute in the Field object, why am I getting this error? and how do I resolve it?

*Environment Specifics*

Running the code on Google Colab

Torchtext version is 0.10.0

Answer (score 1):

After you set your device, you are redefining `TEXT` and `LABEL`. That isn't necessary, and could cause issues. Also, you are setting `use_vocab=False` for your `LabelField`, and then building a vocab for it.

From the [`torchtext` 0.8 docs](https://pytorch.org/text/_modules/torchtext/data/field.html):

> `use_vocab`: Whether to use a `Vocab` object. If `False`, the data in this field should already be numerical. Default: `True`.

I would start by clearing up those issues and see if that resolves your error.